# Prevent <script> tags being sent to loopback data store

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have created a loopback api but have found that i can easily send and save unsanitized property values to the db like: 'alert('hi')'

I've found a few sanitize libraries but it's specifically whether there is something built in to loopback already or if not implementing it globally by default or across multiple properties in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link to create custom validation on loopback models:

http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#validatable-validate

```
User.validate('name', customValidator, {message: 'Bad name'});
function customValidator(err) {
    if (this.name === 'bad') err();
});
var user = new User({name: 'Peter'});
user.isValid(); // true
user.name = 'bad';
user.isValid(); // false
```

Perhaps you could hook a custom sanitize function into here.

Comment: I've found a few sanitize libraries but it's specifically whether there is something built in to loopback already or if not implementing it across multiple properties

Comment: You can use a custom model validation method to check for tags before you insert the data into your database.

Comment: thanks, I saw that, but I was hoping there would be something a little less granular as this is the functionality I would want for all properties by default with the option to turn off.

Comment: I wondered whether it would be more of an express middleware to check form post data for potential XSS